# Insert into master table through integrity constraint exception handling

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

DB: Oracle 11gR2
OS: Windows 7 client

Hello,
I have a master table and a detail table as following:

```
create table country (id     NUMBER not null,      code    VARCHAR2(2) not null, creation_date    date, constraint pk_country_id primary key (code));
create table country_detail (code    VARCHAR2(2), description VARCHAR2(100),  creation_date    date, modify_date    date, constraint fk_country_id foreign key (code) references country(code));

insert into country values(1, 'US', sysdate);
insert into country values(2, 'CA', sysdate); -- missing on DB1
insert into country values(3, 'MX', sysdate);
insert into country values(4, 'CH', sysdate);
insert into country values(5, 'IN', sysdate); -- missing on DB2
insert into country values(6, 'JP', sysdate);

insert into country_detail values('US', 'United States of Ameica', sysdate, sysdate);
insert into country_detail values('CA', 'Canada', sysdate, sysdate); -- missing on DB1
insert into country_detail values('MX', 'Mexico', sysdate, sysdate);
insert into country_detail values('CH', 'Peoples republic of china', sysdate, sysdate);
insert into country_detail values('IN', 'Republic of India', sysdate, sysdate); -- missing on DB2
insert into country_detail values('JP', 'Japan', sysdate, sysdate);
```

Now the country table exists in 2 DBs, but data is not the same, e.g. on DB1 let's say 'CA' is missing and on DB2 'IN' is missing. The above 6 codes can be the max values which can reside in these tables.

Now I want to insert these 6 records in the country_detail table through a (SQL or PL/SQL) script such a way that it should not fail on any DB. I.e. on DB1 when it tries to insert for 'CA' (or on DB2, insert 'IN') it should not fail due to "integrity constraint violated - parent key not found". Rather when it see's the error it should handle in the exception (for PL/SQL or in some kind of SQL statement like merge) section by first inserting data in the country table and then insert the corresponding record in the country_detail table.

The task is to fully sync the data on the 2 databases (i.e. both the environment should have all 6 records in both the tables).

Is there any way this can be done through some kind of SQL statement like Merge. We can insert one by one for each country if it's a SQL statement.

If it can't be done in single SQL then how to implement it in PL/SQL (what kind of error handling will achieve the end result). Note, in PL/SQL I will like process all data in only 1 block ( i.e only 1 {begin ... exception ... end;} block). How this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: This sure seems like a lot of work for 6 records, but a merge should work.

Comment: Try using a DUP val on index and update with the same value

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is easy enough:

```
merge into country c
using(
    select  ID, code, Created
    from(
        select  1 ID, 'US' Code, sysdate Created from dual union all
        select  2, 'CA', sysdate from dual union all
        select  3, 'MX', sysdate from dual union all
        select  4, 'CH', sysdate from dual union all
        select  5, 'IN', sysdate from dual union all
        select  6, 'JP', sysdate from dual
    ) ) v
on( c.Code = v.code )
when not matched then
    insert( id, code, Creation_Date )
    values( v.id, v.code, v.Created );
```

Just change the inline view for the other table as appropriate.

But please allow me a question: what is the purpose of the ID field of the Country table? It's not the primary key, that being the Code field (which I agree is the better choice). It may have been meant to be the PK, but changed when Code presented itself as the better of the two. If it is such a vestigial field, get rid of it.